# pause in batch file not working

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that tests to see if a file exists.
After that, it has to pause.

But pause is not working for some reason.
Any help please. thanks much

```
  if exist C:\autoexec.bat 
  ECHO Folder C:\autoexec.bat exists
  PAUSE
```

---

Pause works at command prompt.

The file exists for sure. But I can't see Echo as well as Pause
The screen just disappears once I run the .bat file

Comment: Pause "works" just fine. Not enough information here to tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Is your problem that the pause is always executed and you only want it to pause when the file exists?

Comment: "not working"? any output? Does it work "standalone" (just `pause` at the command prompt)?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take two-minute [tour] and follow [ask]. "not working" seems to be insufficient…

Comment: shouldn't the pause execute irrespective of the files existence?

Comment: @bnath001 No, If there is syntax error it aborts the script and forces it to end

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to write:

```
if exist C:\autoexec.bat ECHO Folder C:\autoexec.bat exists
PAUSE
```

Note that shell after the if command is expecting a command to execute. If there is no command after de condition it should abort batch with:
"The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Edit. Mr.Helpy Got it first.

Note if you want multiple lines use a block

```
if exist C:\autoexec.bat (
ECHO Folder C:\autoexec.bat exists
REM other commands...
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: putting in block helped.

Comment: what if we have to check multiple files?

Comment: @bnath001 - Use multiple `if`s

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the command. The valid syntax for `if` command is

```
IF [NOT] EXIST filename command 
OR
IF [NOT] EXIST filename (command) ELSE (command)
```

The word `command` at the last is very important. What I did was this

```
@Echo off
if exist C:\autoexec.bat goto hi
if not exist C:\autoexec.bat goto bye
:hi
ECHO Folder C:\autoexec.bat exists
PAUSE
:bye
Echo Folder C:\autoexec.bat does not exists
pause
```

And it worked like a charm

Regards,

See http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Answer (score 2):

Basic troubleshooting: run from a `cmd`window, not per doubleclick.

Then you see, that

```
 if exist C:\autoexec.bat
```

give you a syntax error, that breaks the execution of your batchfile.

`if` expects a command to execute (at the same line), but there isn't one. So the `echo` line is never reached.