# Why does my batch program keep crashing?

Tags: batch-file

I made a (so far 571 line) adventure game, but whenever I choose "3" in this string, it crashes.  Like, it just immediately closes the window.  My only thought is that it might be how choice 1 is set up, but any help would be appreciated.

```
:stayinbed
cls
echo You slowly get out of bed, the monster watches you.
echo.
echo 1) Make a run for it.
echo 2) Begin to teach it how to speak, be nice to it.
echo 3) Get a kitchen knife.
echo.
:loop11
set /p Choice=Choose Now: 
if "%Choice%"=="1" 
cls
gotorun4life3
if "%Choice%"=="2" goto justbenice
if "%Choice%"=="3" goto kitchen
goto loop11

:justbenice
cls
echo You spend the next couple years of your life teaching the creature about life.
echo He is like a child to you, a very disgusting child that is not allowed in public.
echo.
pause
cls
echo You spend decades with him, researching all fields of science.
echo But alas, all good things come to an end.
echo Eventually you contract cancer and die, the monster at your bedside.
pause
goto end1

:kitchen
cls
echo You begin to slowly walk towards your cabinet.
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
echo It watches you, but you keep walking towards the cabinet.
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul
echo You arrive at the cabinet and grab a knife.
echo.
echo 1) Screw it, just run.
echo 2) Kill the abomination.
echo.
:loop12
set /p Choice=Choose Now: 
if "%Choice%"=="1" 
cls
goto run4life3
if "%Choice%"=="2" goto killit
goto loop12


:killit
cls
echo You grasp the knife in your hand and look right at the creature.
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo You run towards it.
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo You stab it in the back of the head.
call :colorEcho 0a "RAAAAUUUGGGHHH"
echo.
echo It falls flat on the ground with a thud.
goto end1
```

Comment: Because you've got `if "%Choice%"=="1"` on a line by itself. Don't do that.

Comment: Start your program from an already open command prompt. Then the window won't close.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35944096/2152082)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in lines:

```
if "%Choice%"=="1" 
cls
gotorun4life3
```

Should be:

```
if "%Choice%"=="1" cls & goto run4life3
```

or

```
if "%Choice%"=="1" (
    cls
    goto run4life3
)
```

When it reaches the line `gotorun4life3` it crashes because it can't parse this command.

Comment: You could also put the `cls` and `goto run4life3` in a code block.

Comment: @SomethingDark what do you mean by that?

Comment: Like that. (I would have posted it in a comment, but comments can't have newlines...)